# Not able to call Super

Tags: java, smartgwt, smartclient

When I invoke this.Super("initWidget") in derived widget, the browser is giving an exception

```
**TypeError: this.Super is not a function**
```

Can anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Insufficient information. Please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

this and super are keywords. this refers to the current object, while super refers to the parent class. If you try to invoke super, you are invoking the super class' constructor. In your case with one parameter. You should use only

```
super("initWidget");
```

because the dot operator after the this means you want to use a method in the current object.

Comment: he is not using keyword super but Super()

Comment: I assumed he want to call the superclass constructor with super, because he didn't provided any sample code, but he talked about derived widget.